# unable to install ubuntu in my gatewaylt41p07u

Tags: system-installation

im having a very difficult time installing ubuntu in my laptop (it has no cd port) and i dont want windows on my computer at all. I'm new at this so Im not familiar with the programs or steps i need to take

Comment: Try with bootable usb.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have iso image of ubuntu. I recommend using [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) software to create bootable usb stick. This software is pretty straight forward and does not need to be installed on system if you are currently on windows. It is also available on Linux.

After bootable USB is created, you can boot your system from this usb by changing bios boot order.

Make sure you have backed up all your important data to external partition(D,E,F etc) or external hard drive. Please refer to ubuntu installation guide before proceeding to start.

I hope it helps.